# Xcode Source Control issue - I've lost my data model and storyboard

Tags: xcode

I started making some changes to my data model this evening and did it all wrong.  I have been doing regular Commits and also pushing my code up to BitBucket, so I decided to do "Discard all changes..." to get rid of tonights changes and start again.

All my .h and .m files are now as of yesterday, but my data model is gone (the file is there but nothing is in it) and the storyboard reverted back to a commit done months ago - it's basically empty too.

I checked BitBucket and the story is the same there too.  No data model and a useless storyboard from months ago. Then I checked another project that I finished a while back and BitBucket has the storyboards and data model up to date for that project.

Two questions:
1. Is there some trick I can use to recover my data model and storyboard?
2. What am I doing wrong that is causing these files not to get committed along with the rest of the project?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and remove your app from device/simulator?

Comment: Yes, and no luck.  I don't understand why everything was fine for the last project, during which I used the same source control strategy.  It looks like it committed my very early storyboard changes - maybe the first couple of commits - then gave up and just left the storyboard file the same no matter what.

Comment: Try to recover from TimeMachine.

Comment: I was relying on source control so no other backups. Turns out a small number of source code files are also old versions.  Very disappointed that I can't trust the source control and BitBucket. Maybe I did something wrong?  Anyway, I'm going to try to fix it manually and also start doing additional backups.